# How do I initialize a 2-D dynamic memory array of pointers with all elements 0

Tags: c++

I want to initialize values of 2-D array to 0. But it seems not to work.
Can I initialize values of my **array in constructor to be 0. If yes the How.
My code is.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
int row, col;
cin>>row;
cin>>col;
int **array=new int*[row];
        for (int i=0; i<row; i++){
            array[i]=new int[col];
        }
            for (int i=0; i<row;i++){
                for (int j=0; j<col; j++){
                    array[i][j]={'0'};
                    cout<<array[i][j]<<" ";
                }
                cout<<endl;
            }
```

}

Further can someone explain if I have to replace ith elem from the array with some other element, how would I deal with memory allocation.

Comment: Use `std::vector<T>` instead of `new T[]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want `array[i][j]=0;`. Why were you using the `char` type `'0'`?
However, there is an easier way: `array[i]=new int[col]();`, just add `()` to value initialize each column.

There also is a better way:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> array(row, std::vector<int>(col));
```

For your first comment, you would need to create a new array with the new size, copy over all the data, and the delete your old 2-d array.

For your second comment, here is an example:

```
struct A
{
    int **array;
    A(int row, int col) : array(new int*[row])
    {
       for (int i=0; i < row; i++)
       {
          array[i]=new int[col]();
       }
    }
};
```

PS: You can save yourself a lot of work by using `std::vector`.

Comment: Can you give answer of my second question too.

Comment: Can I initialize values of my **array in constructor to be 0. If yes the How.

Comment: @HardCode: I update my answer, let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: In case my **array is private and constructor is public. It would work or not.

Comment: @HardCode: It will work (you should also try it out yourself).

Comment: @HardCode: Also, since you are managing a resource, there is a lot of other work you need to do, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) for some help.

Answer (score 1):

this codes works on gcc

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
int row, col;
cin>>row;
cin>>col;
int **array=new int*[row];
    for (int i=0; i<row; i++){
        array[i]=new int[col];
    }
        for (int i=0; i<row;i++){
            for (int j=0; j<col; j++){
                array[i][j]=0;
                cout<<array[i][j]<<" ";
            }
            cout<<endl;
        }
}
```

to replace ith element of the array with some other element we can do something lyk

```
int *aa = new int[p];
swap(array[i], aa)
```

but for this to work logically correct u need to make sure that p >= size of the array array[i] is pointing to. In most of our use cases we have them equal.

Comment: Is there any way that I can set all elem to 0 the time I am initializing a 2-D array so that I don't have to write those extra 2-for loops. I am doing this in a constructor

Comment: whatever way u chose it can only set all elements to 0 by iterating through all the elements.. u may try short-hands to do that.. use stl.. u may use calloc() if u specifically want them to be initialized to 0. but it will anyway endup looping through all the elements and setting them to 0 individually.. so that doesn't matter i guess

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:-

```
class A
{
 public:
 A():my2DArray() {0}
 private:
 B* my2DArray[max1][max2];
 };
```